# Crop PHP string

Tags: php, regex

I store a URL in a variable called *$page*.

I use the following code to grab the *utm_campaign* value.

```
preg_match_all('#utm_campaign=([^\s]+)#', $page, $matches);
$utm_campaign = implode(' ', $matches[1]);
```

However, I find if the URL is *www.site.com/?utm_campaign=test&utm_source=test* it will set `$utm_campaign` equal to *test&utm_source=test* instead of just *test*.

How do I amend my code above to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `&` after `\s`.

See:

```regex
#utm_campaign=([^\s&]+)#
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5SkMLX/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`parse_url`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get your query parameters like so:

```
$url = 'www.site.com/?utm_campaign=test&utm_source=test';
parse_str(parse_url($url)['query'], $params);
print_r($params['utm_campaign']);
```